# Why does Google docs change my 'heading' id

Tags: hyperlink, google-docs

I noticed in my Google document that the id of a heading changes when I press the 'enter key' when I'm focussed in my header. This causes links to this document stop from working since the ID changed. This is of course very frustrating, since the document concerns multiple links to multiple headings.

Am I doing something wrong? Why does google change the id of that heading?

Regards,
Peter

Comment: I found a workaround. I can add manual bookmarks to each heading and reference those (since those id's do not change). But this is of course a lot of manual work

Comment: This workaround is also useless when the header changes numbering. the bookmark will be deleted.